# Using netrw in MacVim does not produce a directory listing

Tags: vim, netrw

Attempting to browse a directory on a machine over vpn.

```
:e scp://user@machine/

If I use the stock vim (7.3) that comes with OSX it returns the result I expect.

" ============================================================================                              
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v140)
"   scp://ssdrive@drivemaster-c38/
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../
./
.altera.quartus/
.cache/
.config/

.
.
.
```

But if I use MacVim (7.4) it just hangs until I ctrl-c.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Darwin, vim 7.4.307, netrw v153h: I do not see this problem.  Stackoverflow isn't really designed as a bug reporting system, so you should contact netrw's author.  However, you might simply want to upgrade your vim and netrw first to see if that helps.
Also: if ssh is throwing an error, netrw might not display it -- so try ssh from the command line first.  For example, if your .ssh/* files are readable by anyone (ie. not r--) then you'll get an empty directory listing.